# How to add element to json data

Tags: java, json

I have a json something like this below .I want to  read it and add 2 more attribute ti it like country and state

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "testname": "test123",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test6"
    }

 {
        "id": "456",
        "testname": "test564",
        "name": "Ship Therasus",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test7"
    }
]
```

Resulting json

```
   [
    {
        "id": "123",
        "testname": "test123",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test6",
        "country":"USA",
         "state":"KA"
    }

 {
        "id": "456",
        "testname": "test564",
        "name": "Ship Therasus",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test7",
         "country":"UK",
         "state":"MA"
    }
]
```

I am doing something like this I tried JSONObject but no  output.

```
JSONArray xmlJSONObj2 = new JSONArray(output);
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n"+xmlJSONObj2.get(0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use for loop to iterate over JSONArray, Once you have jsonObject use put for extra attribute like this

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        // do this for all remaining field
        if(json.has("id")){
            String id = json.get("id").toString();
        }
        // finally put extra attributes to that jsonobject
        json.put("country", "USA");
        json.put("state", "KA")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

missed commas after "type":"test6"

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "testname": "test123",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "active": true,
    "type": "test6" <------
    "country":"USA",
     "state":"KA"
}
```

Comment: Might be worth a comment to clarify that this is the *exact* JSON and not something they have just typed out for an example.

Comment: If it is as @christopher say. Well then I cant really help you. Sorry =)